# Symfony2 custom Twig Extension - Class not found

Tags: php, symfony, twig-extension

I'm having an issue adding in a Twig extension. I'm getting the following error:

```
ClassNotFoundException in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 317:
Attempted to load class "AppExtension" from namespace "HouseBundle\Twig".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

My code:

/Users/Sites/www/houses/src/housesBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php

```
<?php

namespace HouseBundle\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(new \Twig_SimpleFilter('price', array($this, 'priceFilter')),
    );


    public function priceFilter($number, $decimals = 0, $decPoint = '.', $thousandsSep = ',')
    {
        $price = number_format($number, $decimals, $decPoint, $thousandsSep);
        $price = '$'.$price;

        return $price;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

/Users/Sites/www/houses/app/config/services.yml

```
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: HouseBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You've got a problem, your class is finishing just after 'getFilters()' method   ( look the '}' character )

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've corrected it.

Comment: You might just need to clear cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this filepath:

/Users/Sites/www/anildave/houses/src/**housesBundle**/Twig/AppExtension.php

You are using the wrong namespace

```
namespace HouseBundle\Twig;
```

Should be

```
namespace housesBundle\Twig
```

And

```
class: HouseBundle\Twig\AppExtension
```

Should be

```
class: housesBundle\Twig\AppExtension
```

Comment: I cant believe I missed that! Thanks for your he